# Calculate mutual information of twitter's users interactions

Tags: probability, joint-distribution, mutual-information, marginal-distribution

I have a research project about finding out user's interaction on Twitter. If I want to calculate the mutual information between two users A,B: I(A,B), to know the probability of A and B appearing in the same discussion. So how can I calculate this? What can be the p(A), p(B) and p(A,B) in this case? 
As my thought, p(A) is (number of discussions have A)/(total number of discussions)
p(A,B) is (number if discussions have A and B)/(total number of discussions)
Is it correct? I'm not very good at statistical learning so I hope you can explain for me a little bit clearly and in details. Thanks.